# golang form-data payload is visible

Tags: go, web, form-data, visible, payload

I am developing a Golang webpage and I have stumbled upon a problem regarding form submission. I created a form with method=post and upon submission, I can view the form data payload in chrome and firefox. How to avoid this ? Should I be concern about this visibility ?

tks in advance

[image: form data payload visible with username and password :O]

Comment: There is no way to avoid it, that's how HTTP request works.

Comment: Hi tks for your reply Philidor ! but this does not present a security issue right ? this is only visible to the "user" that is requesting ?

Comment: @dhn this is an excellent resource if you are just starting out with web developments and html; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn